# Fetch toilets list using google maps places api

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-places-api

The `Google Map`'s places list does not contain toilets in it, but I need to show toilets list on `Google Maps`. How do I show this data using a `Google API`?

Comment: Anyone please consider the reason while down voting ?

Comment: Are you being serious now? :D

Comment: Can you elaborate and show what you have tried so far (editing your question) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to fetch this data via the iOS SDK. You're better off using the Web Service API instead. i.e Issue an HTTP request via the app and then show the places that exist by iterating through the response.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests is a great place to start. You can use "toilets" or "toilets near me" as the search query.